# How do I upper case an email address?

Tags: email, internationalization

I expect this should be a pretty easy question. It is in two parts:

1. Are email addresses case sensitive? (i.e. is foo@bar.com different from Foo@bar.com?)
2. If so, what is the correct locale to use for capitalising an email address? (i.e. capitalising the email tim@foo.com would be different in the US and Turkish locales)

Comment: if you have anything to do with it, you should aim for case insensitive email names

Comment: Sadly, this won't be the case.

Comment: RFC 822 and its ancestors state that the local part of email addresses (before the @) is case sensitive.  Supporting the populist drive toward case insensitivity adds considerable code complexity to email systems.

Answer (score 13):

Judging from the specs the first part *can* be case sensitive, but normally it's not.
Since it's all ASCII you should be safe using a "naive" uppercase function.

Check out the [RFC spec part of the wikipedia article on E-mail adresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#RFC_specification)

If you're in for some heavier reading [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) and [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) should be useful too.

Answer (score 7):

The local-part of the email address (i.e. before the `@`) **is case-sensitive in general**. From the Wikipedia entry on [E-mail address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address):

> The local-part is case sensitive, so
> "jsmith@example.com" and
> "JSmith@example.com" may be delivered
> to different people. This practice is,
> however, discouraged by [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321).
> However, only the authoritative
> mail-servers for a domain may make
> that decision.

For the detailed specifications, you may wish to consult the following RFCs:

- [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321): Simple Mail Transfer Protocol
- [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322): Internet Message Format
- [RFC 3696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696): Application Techniques for Checking and Transformation of Names

Answer (score 4):

domain names are case insensitive.
so foo@BAR.COM is the same email as foo@bar.com

for user names, it depends of the mail server. in the Outlook server my company uses it is also case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

Email address are not case sensitive.

> The local-part of the e-mail address
>   may use any of these ASCII characters:
>
> 1. Uppercase and lowercase English
>      letters (a-z, A-Z)
> 2. Digits 0 through 9
> 3. Characters ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^
>      _ ` { | } ~
> 4. Character . provided that it is not
>      the first nor last character, nor
>      may it appear two or more times
>      consecutively.
>
>    Source :[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address)